# Node.js http/node-fetch ETIMEDOUT no longer works

Tags: node.js, http, node-fetch

I'm writing an API in Node.JS to protect my API keys for a basic weather app SPA.

Initially my http requests got through fine. The next day (today), with no changes to the request, it fails and I am subjected to a 90-second delay before I receive an unhelpful ETIMEDOUT response.

`connect ETIMEDOUT 2600:1407:3c00:d90::116:80`

I tried switching to node-fetch and got similar results.
I also tried a different api but got the same result, so it must be local to my program.

Can anybody see what's wrong here?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const http = require('http');
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); /* try using node-fetch */



app.use(express.json());

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`it's alive on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);

/* wetter, german for weather */
app.get('/wetter', (req, res) => {

    console.log('got a wetter request');
    var city = req.query.city;
    if(!city){
        res.status(400).send({message: 'Specify a city!'})
    }
    console.log(`city: ${city}`);

    //let url = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=${city}&aqi=no`;
    
    /* weatherapi.com failing. Try weather.gov. */
    let url = 'http://api.weather.gov/';

    console.log(url);
    http.get(url, (res) => {
        let body = '';

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            try {
                let json = JSON.parse(body);
                // Do stuff.
                console.log(json);
            } catch(error) {
                console.error('TRY error: ' + error.message);
            };
        });
    
    }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('GET error: ' + error.message);
    })

    /* http failing. Try node-fetch */
    //let settings = { method: "GET", timeout: "1000" };
    //fetch(url, settings)
    //    .then(res => res.json())
    //    .then((json) => {
    //        console.log(json);
    //    });

    console.log('Done. Sending response.');

    res.status(200).send({
        city: `${city}`,
        forecast: 'forecast-data'
    })
});
```

Comment: Note that Node 18 and up have support for the standard [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Best to move on to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both http and fetch apis are working fine for me. Make sure you are using the right node version.

FYI I am using Node Version 18.17.1